# What is the best way to get access to a jpg file included in your project with GoogleTest?

Tags: c, xcode, googletest

Okay, so I'm using GoogleTest, and I've included an Images folder that includes jpg images that I hope to use in a test.  But I don't want to hardcode the path.

How do I go about referencing via some relative path to the file?

I've looked at getcwd, but of course, I get the Xcode Products/Debug folder.

Then I thought maybe there is a way to copy that jpg image to the build folder somehow?

Recommendations on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, its quick and dirty.  If you find better let me know.

Under the Project Targets -> Build Phase Tab -> Copy Files According Panel.

I used Destination Resources.  Removed the subpath, and removed the checkmark next to Copy Only When Installing.

Clicked the + Added the File.

From GoogleTest, the relative path was

string getImagePath() {
        char cwd[256];

```
    getcwd(cwd,sizeof(cwd));

    stringstream ss;
    ss << cwd << "/image.jpeg";

    return ss.str();
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.